# How can I create a reminder using AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I tried to make a project that will show `Notification` on particular time and even the app is not open it will show it. But it is showing message at particular time and also after the given time. Moreover the `Notification` does not work when the app is closed.

How can I stop it permanently after the given time and also run in the background ?

code is given below.

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 24);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 05);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    Intent into = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent ppendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, into, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManag = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManag.cancel(ppendingIntent);
    ppendingIntent.();
}

 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);

}
```

Receiver has been added to manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 24);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);


AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

final int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```